# Want to change a value continuously from min to max to min in a loop as a Sine curve

Tags: c++, algorithm, cocos2d-x

I am working on a game where I need an algorithm to vary a value in a loop. I have implemented the algorithm but I guess its not working as I want it to work. Here's what I want and what I have already implemented :

Given :

- a commodity whose price I want to circulate (from min to max to min again and continuously in a loop)
- I am using cocos2d-x (C++) where I have a scheduler which runs a function at a given interval say SCHEDULE_INTERVAL
- MIN_PRICE and MAX_PRICE of the commodity
- currentPrice
- Time duration which it will take to complete one cycle (min-max-min)

Current Implementation :

```
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = 0.3 (sec) (so the function is running every 0.3 secs)
counter = 0;
timeDuration = time to complete one cycle

function 
{
  counter++;
  _amplitude = (maxPrice - minPrice)/2;
  _midValue = (maxPrice + minPrice)/2;
  currentPrice = _midValue + _amplitude * sin (2*PI*counter/timeDuration)
}
```

why i am using sine wave : because at the peaks i want to make the transitions slow.

Problem : for some reasons its not behaving the way I want it to behave

I want to continuously change the currentPrice form minPrice-maxPrice-minPrice in timeDuration and the loop running at SCHEDULE_INTERVAL

please suggest any solutions. 
Thanks :)

**EDIT :**
what's not working in the above implementation is that the values are not changing according to the 'timeDuration' variable

Comment: When asking about something which "doesn't work," *always* include information *how* it doesn't work. You've described behaviour you want; describe the behaviour you observe as well.

Comment: It looks OK but you haven't really said what the problem is - "not behaving the way I want" doesn't really tell us anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pseudocode you posted accurately mirrors the expressions you use in real code, you probably want to change the argument of `sin` to this:

```
2 * PI * (counter * SCHEDULE_INTERVAL) / timeDuration
```

`counter` is the *number* of executions, while `timeDuration` is (I presume) the desired length in *seconds.*

In other words, your units don't match - it's always worthwhile to perform a dimensional analysis when formulae don't work.

Comment: this pretty much solve the problem in my implementation. Now the variations are happening according to the time duration.

So when at the peaks (near min and max values) the variation is slow. Is there any way I can control the duration for which the values stays at the peaks, without affecting the rate during the transitions. I mean, is there anyway I can make the values stay a little bit longer at the peaks while the transition still following my usual timeDuration vairable.. ????

Comment: @Aditya The transition is controlled by the entire function (expression) used to compute `currentPrice`. So either use something else instead of `sin`, or scale the argument of `sin` somehow. That's really a math problem, not a programming one.

Comment: Ok... thanks anyway. I guess i have to use some custom function to change the value of currentPrice rather then using basic fundamental math functions.